# Android app crashes when using intent and get method

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm new to Android programming and I'm facing a problem with my first attempts with an app.

I have two activities. ApplicazioneContattoActivity.java (the main one) and ModificaContattoActivity.java.

In the first activity layout there are three textViews with name, surname and phone number of a contact and a button. When the button is pressed, the second activity should start. In the second activity layout there are three editText that should be filled with the values from the first activity.

The values are passed between the activity with an intent and an object.

The problem is that when the button in the first activity is pressed the app crashes. The error is in the part:

```
campoNome.setText(contatto.getNome());
```

Could you please help me to find out what is wrong?

Thank you very much!

First Activity:

```
package com.example.applicazionecontatto;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class ApplicazioneContattoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Contatto mioContatto;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_applicazione_contatto);

        Contatto mioContatto = new Contatto("Mario", "Rossi", "123456");

        TextView nome = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.campoNome);
        TextView cognome = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.campoCognome);
        TextView numero = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.campoNumero);

        nome.setText(mioContatto.getNome());
        cognome.setText(mioContatto.getCognome());

        numero.setText(mioContatto.getNumeroDiTelefono());
    }

    public void modifica(View button){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ModificaContattoActivity.class);
        String pkg = getPackageName();
        intent.putExtra(pkg+".mioContatto", (Serializable) mioContatto);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,  int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        String pkg = getPackageName();
        mioContatto = (Contatto) data.getSerializableExtra(pkg+".nuovoContatto");

        TextView nome = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.campoNome);
        TextView cognome = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.campoCognome);
        TextView numero = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.campoNumero);

        nome.setText(mioContatto.getNome());
        cognome.setText(mioContatto.getCognome());
        numero.setText(mioContatto.getNumeroDiTelefono());
        }
    }


}
```

Second Activity:

```
package com.example.applicazionecontatto;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.io.Serializable;


public class ModificaContattoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.modifica_layout);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        String pkg = getPackageName();

        Contatto contatto = (Contatto) intent.getSerializableExtra(pkg + ".mioContatto");

        EditText campoNome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText1);
        EditText campoCognome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText2);
        EditText campoNumero = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText3);

        campoNome.setText(contatto.getNome());
        campoCognome.setText(contatto.getCognome());
        campoNumero.setText(contatto.getNumeroDiTelefono());

    }


    public void conferma(View button){

        EditText campoNome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText1);
        EditText campoCognome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText2);
        EditText campoNumero = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText3);

        String nome = campoNome.getText().toString();
        String cognome = campoCognome.getText().toString();
        String numero = campoNumero.getText().toString();

        Contatto nuovoContatto = new Contatto(nome, cognome, numero);

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        String pkg = getPackageName();
        intent.putExtra(pkg+".nuovoContatto", (Serializable)nuovoContatto);

        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();

    }
}
```

Class Contatto:

```
package com.example.applicazionecontatto;


import java.io.Serializable;

public class Contatto implements Serializable{

    private String nome;
    private String cognome;
    private String numeroDiTelefono;

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getCognome() {
        return cognome;
    }

    public void setCognome(String cognome) {
        this.cognome = cognome;
    }

    public String getNumeroDiTelefono() {
        return numeroDiTelefono;
    }

    public void setNumeroDiTelefono(String numeroDiTelefono) {
        this.numeroDiTelefono = numeroDiTelefono;
    }

    public Contatto(String nome, String cognome, String numeroDiTelefono) {
        super();
        this.nome = nome;
        this.cognome = cognome;
        this.numeroDiTelefono = numeroDiTelefono;
    }

}
```

Comment: Post the logcat output. As it is now you haven't even told us what the error is.

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Comment: The error was java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.applicazionecontatto.Contatto.getNome()' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a `NullPointerException`, it's because when you initialize `mioContatto`, you are redeclaring the variable instead of initializing the class member. So, instead of doing:

```
Contatto mioContatto = new Contatto("Mario", "Rossi", "123456");
```

Do this:

```
mioContatto = new Contatto("Mario", "Rossi", "123456");
```

This will most likely fix your error if you are getting a NullPointerException.

Comment: Not a problem! Happy coding!